# What good does zero-fill bit-shifting by 0 do? (a >>> 0)

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I just came across [this piece](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf) in the Mozilla Javascript documentation:

```
var len = this.length >>> 0;
```

I don't quite understand why this is being done. What good does zero-fill right shifting `this.length` by `0` do? As far as I understand, it does exactly nothing. Is it to safely establish a default value for `len`, even if `this.length` is not an integer? Can this ever feasibly be the case? If so, what's the difference between `>> 0` and `>>> 0`?