# What is the idiomatic way of performing an "integer " conversion/typecast in javascript?

Tags: javascript, integer, idioms

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0)  asked about the meaning of the code snippet `a >>> 0` in Javascript.  It turns out that it is a clever way of ensuring that a variable is a unsigned 32-bit integer.

This is pretty neat, but I don't like it for two reasons.

- The intent of the expression is not clear, at least not to me.
- It does not work for negative numbers

This leads me to ask: **What is the most idiomatic way of converting an arbitrary value to an "integer" in Javascript?**  It should work for signed integers, not just non-negative numbers.  Cases where this breaks due to the fact that integers are just floats in disguise in Javascript are acceptable, but should be acknowledged.  It should not return `undefined` or `NaN` in any case (these are not integers), but return `0` for non-numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#parseInt_and_parseFloat_Functions) is the “most idiomatic” way, as it exactly describes what you want it to do. The drawback of `parseInt` is that it return `NaN` if you input a non-numeric string.

Another method is bitwise ORing by 0 (`| 0`), which also works for negative numbers. Moreover, it returns `0` when using it on a non-numeric string. Another advantage is that it is a bit faster than `parseInt` when using it on real numbers; it is slower when feeding it strings.

- `12.4 | 0` outputs `12`
- `-12.4 | 0` outputs `-12`
- `"12.4" | 0` outputs `12`
- `"not a number" | 0` outputs `0`

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I want.  `parseInt("not an int, damnit")` returns `NaN`.

Comment: The `|0` he mentioned does work pretty much what you want: strings are 0, `true` is 1, `28.3` is 28, `-28.3` is -28, NaN (as in e.g. `(+"foo")|0`) is 0, `undefined` is 0. Did I miss anything?