# Why does setTimeout() "break" for large millisecond delay values?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I came across some unexpected behavior when passing a large millisecond value to `setTimeout()`. For instance,

```
setTimeout(some_callback, Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

and

```
setTimeout(some_callback, Infinity);
```

both cause `some_callback` to be run almost immediately, as if I'd passed `0` instead of a large number as the delay.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because it's limited to 32-bit, which is 2 power 32.  If you calculate it you get 4294967296. Now, you need the first bit to decide whether it is a negative or positive number. So you get 2 power 31 and you get half of 4294967296, which is 2147483648. But zero is a positive number so 2147483647.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This is due to setTimeout using a 32 bit int to store the delay so the max value allowed would be

```
2147483647
```

if you try

```
2147483648
```

you get your problem occurring.

I can only presume this is causing some form of internal exception in the JS Engine and causing the function to fire immediately rather than not at all.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm guessing it doesn't actually raise an internal exception. Instead, I see it either (1) causing an integer overflow, or (2) internally coercing the delay to an unsigned 32-bit int value. If (1) is the case, then I'm really passing a negative value for the delay. If it's (2), then something like [`delay >>> 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/) happens, so the delay passed is zero. Either way, the fact that the delay is stored as a 32-bit unsigned int explains this behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Old update, but i've just found the max limit is `49999861776383` (`49999861776384` causes the callback to fire instantly)

Comment: @maxp That's because `49999861776383 % 2147483648 === 2147483647`

Comment: @DavidDaSilvaContín really late to this, but can you explain further? Can't understand why 2147483647 isn't the limit?

Comment: @NickCoad both numbers would delay the same amount (i.e. 49999861776383 is same as 2147483647 from a signed 32 bit point of view). write them out in binary, and take the last 31 bits, they will all be 1s.

Comment: Easy to remember because "the number 2,147,483,647 is the eighth Mersenne prime, equal to 2^31 − 1. It is one of only four known double Mersenne primes." [wikipedia]

Comment: `setTimeout` has note about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value

Answer (score 33):

You can use:

```
function runAtDate(date, func) {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var then = date.getTime();
    var diff = Math.max((then - now), 0);
    if (diff > 0x7FFFFFFF) //setTimeout limit is MAX_INT32=(2^31-1)
        setTimeout(function() {runAtDate(date, func);}, 0x7FFFFFFF);
    else
        setTimeout(func, diff);
}
```

Comment: this is cool, but we loose the ability to useClearTimeout due to the recursion.

Comment: You don't really lose ability to cancel it provided that you do your bookkeeping and replace timeoutId you want to cancel inside this function.

Answer (score 30):

Some explanation here: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_timer_timer.js.source.html

> Timeout values too big to fit into a signed 32-bit integer may cause
>   overflow in FF, Safari, and Chrome, resulting in the timeout being
>   scheduled immediately.  It makes more sense simply not to schedule these
>   timeouts, since 24.8 days is beyond a reasonable expectation for the
>   browser to stay open.

Comment: warpech's answer makes a lot of sense - a long running process like a Node.JS server might sound like an exception, but to be honest if you've got something that you want to ensure happens in exactly 24 and a bit days with millisecond accuracy then you should use something more robust in the face of server and machine errors than setTimeout...

Comment: @cfogelberg, I have not seen the FF or any other implementation of the `setTimeout()`, but I would hope that they calculate the date and time when it should wake up and do not decrement a counter on some randomly defined tick... (One can hope, at least)

Comment: I'm running Javascript in NodeJS on a server, 24.8 days is still good, but I'm looking for a more logical way to set an callback to happen in say 1 month (30 days). What would be the way to go for this?

Comment: I have, for sure, had browser windows open longer than 24.8 days. It's bizarre to me that browsers don't internally do something like Ronen's solution, at least up to MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Who says?  I keep my browser open way longer than 24 days... ;)

Comment: If you are using NodeJS on a server, like @Paul, give a look at [node-cron](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron)

Answer (score 8):

Check out the node doc on Timers here: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html (assuming same across js as well since it's such an ubiquitous term now in event loop based

In short:

*When delay is larger than 2147483647 or less than 1, the delay will be set to 1.*

and delay is:

*The number of milliseconds to wait before calling the callback.*

Seems like your timeout value is being defaulted to an unexpected value along these rules, possibly?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this when I tried to automatically logout a user with an expired session. My solution was to just reset the timeout after one day, and keep the functionality to use clearTimeout.

Here is a little prototype example:

```
Timer = function(execTime, callback) {
    if(!(execTime instanceof Date)) {
        execTime = new Date(execTime);
    }

    this.execTime = execTime;
    this.callback = callback;

    this.init();
};

Timer.prototype = {

    callback: null,
    execTime: null,

    _timeout : null,

    /**
     * Initialize and start timer
     */
    init : function() {
        this.checkTimer();
    },

    /**
     * Get the time of the callback execution should happen
     */
    getExecTime : function() {
        return this.execTime;
    },

    /**
     * Checks the current time with the execute time and executes callback accordingly
     */
    checkTimer : function() {
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);

        var now = new Date();
        var ms = this.getExecTime().getTime() - now.getTime();

        /**
         * Check if timer has expired
         */
        if(ms <= 0) {
            this.callback(this);

            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Check if ms is more than one day, then revered to one day
         */
        var max = (86400 * 1000);
        if(ms > max) {
            ms = max;
        }

        /**
         * Otherwise set timeout
         */
        this._timeout = setTimeout(function(self) {
            self.checkTimer();
        }, ms, this);
    },

    /**
     * Stops the timeout
     */
    stopTimer : function() {
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
var timer = new Timer('2018-08-17 14:05:00', function() {
    document.location.reload();
});
```

And you may clear it with the `stopTimer` method:

```
timer.stopTimer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment but to answer all the people.
It takes unsigned value ( you can't wait negative milliseconds obviously )
So since max value is "2147483647" when you enter a higher value it start going from 0.

**Basically delay = {VALUE} % 2147483647.**

So using delay of 2147483648 would make it 1 millisecond, therefore, instant proc.

Comment: This is wrong. A value of `2787431818` will also run it instantly even though `2787431818  % 2147483647` is 639948171ms

Answer (score -3):

```
Number.MAX_VALUE
```

is actually not an integer.  The maximum allowable value for setTimeout is likely 2^31 or 2^32.  Try

```
parseInt(Number.MAX_VALUE)
```

and you get 1 back instead of 1.7976931348623157e+308.

Comment: This is incorrect: `Number.MAX_VALUE` is an integer. It is the integer 17976931348623157 with 292 zeros after. The reason `parseInt` returns `1` is because it first converts its argument to a string and then searches the string from left to right. As soon as it finds the `.` (which isn't a number), it stops.

Comment: By the way, if you want to test if something is an integer, use the ES6 function `Number.isInteger(foo)`. But since it's not supported yet, you can use `Math.round(foo) === foo` instead.

Comment: @Pauan, implementation wise, `Number.MAX_VALUE` is not an integer but a `double`. So there is that... A double can represent an integer, though, since it is used to save integers of 32 bits in JavaScript.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes, of course JavaScript implements **all** numbers as 64-bit floating point. If by "integer" you mean "32-bit binary" then `Number.MAX_VALUE` is not an integer. But if by "integer" you mean the mental concept of "an integer", then it is an integer. In JavaScript, because all numbers are 64-bit floating point, it is common to use the mental concept definition of "integer."

Comment: There's also `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` but that's not the number we're looking for here either.