# Is it possible to make an alarm in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to ser a function to start in a given date and hour? How?

I thought about setTimeout, but what's the maximum time I can set?

**--update**

By the way, it's for a desktop application.

Comment: I don't think there is any limit on `setTimeout`, other than the user closing the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with JCOC611 - if you can make sure that your application does not close, then just get a `Date` object of when your alarm should go off and do something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { soundAlarm() }, 
           alarmDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime());
```

I see no reason for this not to work, but a lot of people exalt a timer based solution where you have a short lived timer that ticks until the set time. It has the advantage that the timer function can also update a clock or a countdown. I like to write this pattern like this:

```
(function(targetDate) {
    if (targetDate.getTime() <= new Date().getTime()) {
        soundAlarm();
        return;
    }

    // maybe update a time display here?
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000,targetDate); // tick every second
})(alarmDate);
```

This is basically a function that when called with a target date to sound an alarm on, re-calls itself every second to check if the time has not elapsed yet.

Comment: I found this page, which my actual answer: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=173924

Comment: Its a similar notion, though I think the guy's original problem was that he refreshes the page every 15 minutes or so even if you don't do anything else and thus he gets his timer unset when the page unloads. If you make sure your page never unloads (which makes sense for a desktop application) then you don't have that problem. But still - see my edit of the answer for a solution similar to the answers on the page you found.

Comment: re-calls itself every second: this will increase the stack without bound, which is a dangerous memory leak. Why not use `setInterval()` instead?

Comment: "Recalls" is a description of the effect, not the mechanic - please see the code. It sets a timer to rerun itself. The advantage of this approach over `setInterval` is that there is no interval registration code to keep track of and remember to unregister - just eventually the code will stop setting a timeout. Reduces global variable noise.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(functionToCall,delayToWait)
```

As stated in [Why does setTimeout() "break" for large millisecond delay values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values), it uses a 32 bit int to store the delay so the max value allowed would be 2147483647

Comment: your syntax is a bit broken: the use of `functionToCall()` in this way would actually execute the function before executing `setTimeout()` and then `setTimeout()` will get its return value as the method to execute when the timeout expires.

Comment: @Guss: Yes uhm... ops! ;D I mistakenly added the parenthesis.

Comment: Nice info, that would be about 596 hours!

Comment: Which comes out to 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should not relay on setTimeout for the actual alarm trigger but for a periodic function tracking the alarm. Use setTimeout to check the stored time for your alarm say every minute. Store that time in DB, file or server.

Answer (score 1):

Does setTimeout() have a maximum?

http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/settimeout-ecma-166425.html

> It may surprise you that setTimeout is
>   not covered by an ECMA standard, nor
>   by a W3C standard. There are some
>   holes in the web standards. This is
>   one of them. I'm looking to the WHAT
>   Working Group to fix this. See
>   http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/
>
> There doesn't seem to be a problem in
>   setting the timeout value to something
>   that is vastly greater than the MTBF
>   of the browser. All that means is that
>   the timeout may never fire.
>
> http://javascript.crockford.com/
>   -Douglas Crockford

As others have mentioned, this isn't the way to handle the situation.  Use setTimeout to check a date object and then fire the event at the appropriate time.  Some code to play with is linked below.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Answer (score 0):

Is there any server component to this at all?  You could use setInterval to call something serverside on a regular basis via ajax, then pull back a date object and once it's finally in the past you could trigger your "alarm"

Comment: as mentioned this will create a lot of noise and prone to memory leak