# JQuery animation does not work

Tags: animation

Well, I have an image which animates by moving to the left by 1000px. Once it stops, this image is replaced to another image. My code:

```
function image1() {
    $('#photo').animate({left: '1000px'}, 40000, function() {
        $('#photo').attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
       setTimeout(image1, "2000")
    });
}
```

The image doe move, but when it stops, it does not change.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(image1, 2000)
```

instead of this

```
setTimeout(image1, "2000")
```

Comment: it works now, my bad, the mistake was the ID was in a div which envelops the image.. so i removed the ID to put it in the image lol... thank you... IT WORKS DUDE :)

Comment: by the way, once the image changes, can it be animated now? i mean when the image changes to the other image, the latter animates and move to the left by 1000px. For example, I made this but does not work:


function image1() {
    $('#photo').animate({left: '1000px'}, 40000, function() {
        $('#photo').attr('src', 'image2.jpg').animate({left: '1000px'}, 40000);
       setTimeout(image1, 2000)
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

To start, the second argument to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) should be a number [(less than `2^31`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values), not a string.

```
setTimeout(image1, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) instead of repeating the selector.