# Making Discord bot do things automatically on a daily routine

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new to java script and discord programming and I want a bot at my discord server to do a channel purge at 5o'clock in the morning.
However, I want to run it on a dedicated server and don't know how to properly set up the time trigger mechanic.
Will

```
if (date.getHours()==5){
   //do stuff
}
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`client.setInterval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval) to have timed functions.

For example: `client.setInterval(() => purgeChannel(), 300000);` will run the function `purgeChannel` every 5 minutes (300000 is 5 minutes in milliseconds).

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot set a specific starting point in time?

Comment: If you want to use a specific time then this might be your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089196/13176517

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could see you doing this, was an Object with each action saved to a time. I choose to use `<HOUR><MINUTE>` to store each value. So a 4:12PM time would be: `1612`. Then a `setInterval` to run every minute and check if it needs todo a new action.

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('Hello');
}
let actions = {
  "0630": function() {
    console.log('Its 6:30');
  },
  "1200": hello, //NOON
  "1400": hello, //2:00 PM
  "0000": function() {
    console.log('New Day / Midnight');
  },
};
let codeStartTime = new Date();

function checkActions() {
  let date = new Date();
  let action = actions[`${date.getHours() >= 10 ? "" : "0"}${date.getHours()}${date.getMinutes() >= 9 ? "" : "0"}${date.getMinutes()}`];
  if (typeof action === "function") action(); //If an action exists for this time, run it.
}
setTimeout(function() {
  checkActions();
  setInterval(checkActions, 60000); //Run the function every minute. Can increase/decrease this number
}, ((60 - codeStartTime.getSeconds()) * 1000) - codeStartTime.getMilliseconds()); // Start the interval at the EXACT time it starts at a new minute


/** CODE for the Stack Overflow Snippet **/
console.log(`Starting first interval in ${((60 - codeStartTime.getSeconds()))} seconds.`);
console.log(`Adding in StackOverflow function, set to run at: ${codeStartTime.getHours() >= 10 ? "" : "0"}${codeStartTime.getHours()}${codeStartTime.getMinutes() >= 9 ? "" : "0"}${codeStartTime.getMinutes() + 1}`);
actions[`${codeStartTime.getHours() >= 10 ? "" : "0"}${codeStartTime.getHours()}${codeStartTime.getMinutes() >= 9 ? "" : "0"}${codeStartTime.getMinutes() + 1}`] = function() {
  console.log('Ran the StackOverflow Function');
};
```

If you choose to, you can wait for the any of my example times in the `actions` Object just to prove it works. But the **StackOverflow** code just adds a sample time to your current time +1 minute in the `actions` Object just to make it easier to see it in action.

`setInterval` is used here just to be simple, but not really recommended if this will run all day. [Reason Why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089196/9853037).
*To have a more exact time*, I suggest replacing the `setInterval` to a `setTimeout` and just re-define the `setTimeout` everytime it's ran.