# How to trigger a script on a certain time on GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm livestreaming a event on a webpage and I'd like to trigger a scripts at certain time(for example, 15:00), not by elapsed time.

Is it possible on Google Tag Mangaer to handle such trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you can combine it with whatever function call you need and this :
[How to run a function at specific time & date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088040/how-to-run-a-function-at-specific-time-date)

So because it depends on the timezone you want to execute it you'd just need to set it properly as per the hours you're using on your hosted website.

Add an event listener on a condition where you'd trigger the certain function upon a condition.

There's examples in the link, leave a comment if you'd need further examples.