# setTimeout with given time in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider this:

```js
setTimeout(function(){...}, 1000);
```

It runs the function after 1 second. I was confused if I want to a function runs at 08:30:00 but my script starts just now (`Date.now()`), how should I estimate the milliseconds until then?

Comment: Are you asking because you do not wish to use any of the available libraries such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron ?

Comment: @cYrixmorten Yes I don't want to use libraries.

Comment: In that case I think you could get inspiration from momentjs for the logic around the diff function to get the diff in ms between now and 8:30.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thanks.

Comment: This post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088040/how-to-run-a-function-at-specific-time-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a date that is the same day as the day that the page is being accessed and set the time portion of that date to 8:30. Then you can simply subtract the current time from that time to get the difference in milliseconds. Once you know the difference, you can set your timer for that delay.

```js
let now = new Date();
console.log("Current time is: " + now.toLocaleTimeString()); 

let targetTime = new Date();
targetTime.setHours(20);    // 8 pm
targetTime.setMinutes(30);  // 30 minutes
targetTime.setSeconds(0);   // 0 seconds
console.log("Target time is: " + targetTime.toLocaleTimeString()); // 8:30 PM

let delay = targetTime - now; // Get difference in milliseconds
console.log(delay + " milliseconds (" + delay/1000 + " seconds, " + (delay/1000/60).toFixed(2) + " minutes"  + ") until 8:30");

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("time's up!");
}, delay);
```

Comment: Great help with great explanation. Thank you.