# javascript setTimout not stopping for specifc time

Tags: jquery

I have the following code;

```
$("#main-iframe").load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("hello");
    },3000000000)
});
```

In the above case the alert box should appear after 30000000000 milseconds, but it is appearing immediately once the `main-iframe` is loaded?

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Do you suppose the browser will run for more than one month ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does setTimeout() "break" for large millisecond delay values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum allowed number of millis is `2147483647` (*32 bit int*) you are using greater then that i.e `3000000000`