# Delay each loop iteration in node js, async

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have the code below:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require ("cheerio");
var async= require("async");

var MyLink="www.mylink.com";

    async.series([

        function(callback){
            request(Mylink, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) return callback(error); 
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                //Some calculations where I get NewUrl variable...
                TheUrl=NewUrl;
                callback();
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            for (var i = 0; i <=TheUrl.length-1; i++) {
                var url = 'www.myurl.com='+TheUrl[i];
                request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 
                    if (error) return callback(error); 
                    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                    //Some calculations again...
                    callback();
                });
            };
        }
      ], function(error){
        if (error) return next(error);
    });
```

Does anyone have a suggestion about how I can delay each loop iteration in the `for loop`? Say, the code waits 10 seconds after each iteration is complete. I tried `setTimeout` but didn't manage that to work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set a timeout for the execution of the code at increasing intervals like this:

```
var interval = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds;

for (var i = 0; i <=TheUrl.length-1; i++) {
    setTimeout( function (i) {
        var url = 'www.myurl.com='+TheUrl[i];
        request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 
            if (error) return callback(error); 
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            //Some calculations again...
            callback();
        });
    }, interval * i, i);
}
```

So the first one runs right away (interval * 0 is 0), second one runs after ten seconds, etc.

You need to send `i` as the final parameter in the `setTimeout()` so that its value is bound to the function argument. Otherwise the attempt to access the array value will be out of bounds and you will get `undefined`.

Comment: Why can't I change the next last line from `}, interval * i, i);` to `}, interval * 1, i);`, from `i to 1`? Code does not work then, if I want a constant intervall.

Comment: `setTimeout()` returns immediately. It does not sit there and wait until the timeout before returning control to the `for` loop. So if you use `interval * 1` (which is the same as just `interval`, then you are running everything ten seconds in the future all at once (more or less--they will be a few milliseconds apart, but that's it). But if you use `interval * i`, that's "right away" the first time through, "ten seconds in the future" the second time through the loop, "twenty seconds in the future" the third time, etc.

Comment: Ok, tried `interval*1` but got no results... But I understand what you mean! Thansk.

Comment: note that setTimeout has a maximum number and this will break if it reaches 2147483647 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values

Answer (score 41):

## Delaying multiple page fetches with `async/await`

I am a big fan of the async library and I've used for a long time. However, now there's [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Your code becomes easier to read. For instance, this would be your main function:

```
const urls = await fetchUrls(INITIAL_URL);

for (const url of urls) {
    await sleep(10000);
    const $ = await fetchPage(url);
    // do stuff with cheerio-processed page
}
```

Much better, isn't it? Before I get into the details of how `fetchPage()` and `fetchUrls()` work, let's first answer your question of how to wait before fetching the next page. The sleep function is pretty straightforward:

```
async function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}
```

You can get a full explanation of how it works in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720712/778272).

Ok, back to the other functions. The `request` library has a promise-enabled version of it that you can use with `async/await`. Let's check how's `fetchPage()` implemented:

```
async function fetchPage(url) {
    return await request({
        url: url,
        transform: (body) => cheerio.load(body)
    });
}
```

Since `request` is returning a promise, we can `await` on it. I also took the chance to use the `transform` property which allows us to tranform the response body before resolving the promise. I'm passing it through Cheerio, just like you did in your code.

Finally, `fetchUrls()` can just call `fetchPage()` and process it to fetch your array of URLs before resolving its promise. Here's the full code:

```
const
    request = require("request-promise-native"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio");

const
    INITIAL_URL = "http://your-initial-url.com";

/**
 * Asynchronously fetches the page referred to by `url`.
 *
 * @param {String} url - the URL of the page to be fetched
 * @return {Promise} promise to a cheerio-processed page
 */
async function fetchPage(url) {
    return await request({
        url: url,
        transform: (body) => cheerio.load(body)
    });
}

/**
 * Your initial fetch which will bring the list of URLs your looking for.
 *
 * @param {String} initialUrl - the initial URL
 * @return {Promise<string[]>} an array of URL strings
 */
async function fetchUrls(initialUrl) {
    const $ = await fetchPage(initialUrl);
    // process $ here and get urls
    return ["http://foo.com", "http://bar.com"];
}

/**
 * Clever way to do asynchronous sleep. 
 * Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720712/778272
 *
 * @param {Number} millis - how long to sleep in milliseconds
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}

async function run() {
    const urls = await fetchUrls(INITIAL_URL);
    for (const url of urls) {
        await sleep(10000);
        const $ = await fetchPage(url);
        // do stuff with cheerio-processed page
    }
}

run();
```

To use `request` with promises, install it like this:

```
npm install request
npm install request-promise-native
```

And then `require("request-promise-native")` in your code, like in the example above.

Answer (score 18):

Another alternative would be to use `async.eachSeries`. For example:

```
async.eachSeries(TheUrl, function (eachUrl, done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var url = 'www.myurl.com='+eachUrl;
        request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 
            if (error) return callback(error); 
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            //Some calculations again...
            done();
        });
    }, 10000);
}, function (err) {
    if (!err) callback();
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Since you're already using `async`, `async.wilst` would do nicely as a replacement for `for`.

`whilst` is an asynchronous `while`-like function. Each iteration is only run after the previous iteration has called its completion callback. In this case, we can simply postpone execution of the completion callback by 10 seconds with `setTimeout`.

```
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
    // test to perform next iteration
    function() { return i <= TheUrl.length-1; },

    // iterated function
    // call `innerCallback` when the iteration is done
    function(innerCallback) {
        var url = 'www.myurl.com='+TheUrl[i];
        request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 
            if (error) return innerCallback(error); 
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            //Some calculations again...

            // wait 10 secs to run the next iteration
            setTimeout(function() { i++; innerCallback(); }, 10000);
        });
    },

    // when all iterations are done, call `callback`
    callback
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a delay at a specific time? In example each 30 minutes?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample code to provide a delay in a for a loop.

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
};

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    console.log(index);
    sleep(1000);
}
```