# Infinite jasmine timeout

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

This is basically a follow-up to [Remove timeout for single jasmine spec](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1642) github issue.

**The question:**

Is it possible to make a single test never timeout?

**The problem:**

It is possible to set a timeout value globally via [`DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-47) or for every describe with `beforeEach`/`afterEach` or on a single `it()` block:

```
it('Has a custom timeout', function() {
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
}, value in msec)
```

I'm interested in having a single spec never timeout. I've tried to follow the advice proposed in the mentioned github issue and use `Infinity`:

```
it('Has a custom timeout', function() {
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
}, Infinity)
```

but, I've got the following error immediately after the tests got into the `it()` block:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

I guess I cannot use `Infinity` as a timeout value, or I'm doing something wrong.

---

As a workaround, I can use a hardcoded large number instead, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for having a spec which never times out?

Comment: @finspin that's a good question. I have a long running test that can take a significant amount of time to complete. Strictly speaking it cannot be infinite and there are sane limits to it's execution time. But, I am actually curious if it is possible to have an infinite timeout. Thanks. And, having `Infinity` as a timeout value as opposed to `1000000` I think would make me feel better about the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jasmine internally uses `setTimeout` to wait for specs to finish for a defined period of time.

According to this Q/A - [Why does setTimeout() "break" for large millisecond delay values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values):

> setTimeout using a 32 bit int to store the delay
>
> ...
>
> Timeout values too big to fit into a signed 32-bit integer may cause
>   overflow in FF, Safari, and Chrome, resulting in the timeout being
>   scheduled immediately. It makes more sense simply not to schedule
>   these timeouts, since 24.8 days is beyond a reasonable expectation for
>   the browser to stay open.

As soon as `Infinity` is greater than any other number the overflow occurs.

The max safe integer in this case is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 =  2147483647. This value is finite, so the test won't actually run infinitely long, but as said I think 24.8 days is long enough.

You can define a constant to store this value:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 2000;

var MAX_SAFE_TIMEOUT = Math.pow(2, 31) - 1;

describe('suite', function () {

  it('should work infinitely long', function (done) {

    setTimeout(function () {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
      done();
    }, 3000)

  }, MAX_SAFE_TIMEOUT);

});
```

[See working sample here](http://jsbin.com/cijidifoni/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation once again!