# Can't set timeout for jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I've tried all the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867601/how-do-i-change-the-timeout-on-a-jasmine-node-async-spec) but none of them work for me.

I'm using `jasmine v2.3.2` and `jasmine-core v2.3.4`

When I do this test:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL= 999999;

describe('tests content controller', function(){
//...

    fit('/content should return 200',function(done){
        request(app)
        .get('/content?type=script')
        .set('Authorization', "bearer " + requestor.token)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) done.fail(err);
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
            console.log('got here');
            console.log(jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL); //prints 30000
            done();
        })
    },999999);
```

I see on my console that the request took only 3000 milliseconds. I even see my `got here` log.

The log that shows the timeout prints out `30000` and not `999999` like I expect.

I also get a failure for this test with the message:

```
Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 33.069 seconds
```

There is some initial setup which causes the majority of this ~30 second delay. The application has to connect to several databases and run the `beforeAll` function in the `describe`.

How can I get prevent jasmine from timing out like this?

Comment: `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` should be on the top level code. Have you tried to put it outside of any `describe`?

Comment: @just-boris yes. I've updated my code to show that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting the `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` in a `beforeAll`, since the timeout interval is reset for each `it` block:

```
describe("testing timeout", function() {
    beforeAll(function() {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 999999;
    });

    fit('should have custom timeout', function(){
        console.log(jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL); //prints 999999
    });
})
```

Also, keep in mind that setTimeout is using a 32 bit integer to store the delay behind the scenes, so integer values that exceed this will cause overflow.  See this post:
[Infinite jasmine timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336575/infinite-jasmine-timeout)

Comment: Jasmine's current (2.5.38) behavior is not as you described it. A custom timeout set in a `beforeAll` block is present in each `it` block.

Comment: ARH. I read a guide saying the third parameter was number of retries. Turns out, it's actually timeout in jasmine `this.it = function(description, fn, timeout) {`