# How do I trigger only on key enter in filter of primeNG datatables angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG datatables angular 2.
How do I only trigger the filter of primeNG datatable when the enter key is pressed?

Base code:

HTML:

```
div class="container-fluid single-col-full-width-container">
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px 10px;border-bottom: 0 none">
    <i class="fa fa-search" style="float:right;margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
    <input #gb type="text" pInputText size="50" style="float:right" placeholder="Filter...">
  </div>
  <div class="ContentSideSections Implementation">
    <p-dataTable
      #reprintGrid
      [value]="datasource"
      [(selection)]="jobs"
      (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
      [paginator]="true"
      [rows]="10"
      [responsive]="true"
      [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
      [lazy]="true"
      (onLazyLoad)="getNewDatasource($event)"
      [pageLinks]="10"
      [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
      [globalFilter]="gb"
    >
      <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
      <p-column *ngFor="let col of columnDefs" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.headerName" [sortable]="true">
      </p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS file:

```
export class ReprintModuleComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Athlete',
      field: 'athlete'
    },
    {headerName: 'Age', field: 'age'},
    {headerName: 'Country', field: 'country'},
    {headerName: 'Year', field: 'year'},
    {headerName: 'Date', field: 'date'},
    {headerName: 'Sport', field: 'sport'},
    {headerName: 'Gold', field: 'gold'},
    {headerName: 'Silver', field: 'silver'},
    {headerName: 'Bronze', field: 'bronze'},
    {headerName: 'Total', field: 'total'}
  ];

  datasource=[];
  jobs = [];
  totalRecords: number;
  pngService: PrimeNgCommonService;
  @ViewChild('reprintGrid') reprintGrid;
  @ViewChild('gb') globalFilter;

  getNewDatasource(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    //in a real application, make a remote request to load data using state metadata from event
    //event.first = First row offset
    //event.rows = Number of rows per page
    //event.sortField = Field name to sort with
    //event.sortOrder = Sort order as number, 1 for asc and -1 for dec
    //filters: FilterMetadata object having field as key and filter value, filter matchMode as value

    let obsResponse = this.pjService.sampleData();
    obsResponse.subscribe(
      res => {
        this.datasource = res;
        this.totalRecords = res.length;
      }
    );       
  }

  constructor(private pjService: PrintJobService) {
    this.pngService = PrimeNgCommonService.getInstance();
  }

  onRowSelect(event) {

  }
}
```

How do I override the filtering of datatables to only trigger on key enter pressed?

Comment: Much easier to help if you provide the code you have where you tried this, and explain what didn't work, or any errors you received

Comment: uuhh? no need for code. that's exactly the problem. I do not know how to only trigger the filtering on key enter pressed. But I can give you the base code. i'll update my post

Answer (score 2):

Officially that's not posible... but I could do this by manipulating the `filterDelay` attribute and using the [key event](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#key-event-filtering-with-key-enter-) feature of Angular 2 , I'll write a general version of how to do this.

---

**TS file**

```
import {DataTable} from "primeng/components/datatable/datatable";

@Component({
    templateUrl: '.../some.component.html'
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(('myDT')) dataTableX: DataTable;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // I used this number by (1)
        this.dataTableX.filterDelay = 2147483647;
    }

    filter(){
        this.dataTableX.filterDelay = -1;
    }

    reset(){
        this.dataTableX.filterDelay = 2147483647;
    }
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<p-dataTable #myDT (keydown.enter)="filter()" (keyup.enter)="reset()" >
    <p-column field="fieldx" header="Column name" [filter]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

---

I tested using:

- Primeng 1.0.0-beta.17
- Angular 2.0.0 Final release

(1)The number of delay for automatic filter is approximately 24 days. Cannot use Infinity, Number.MAX_VALUE or Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER because the browsers use [32 bits int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values).

I hope this is helpful.