# How can I use setTimeout with bigint?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to use setTimeout with a bigint to avoid exceeding the 32 bit integer limit(which did happened in my code) while incrmenting the timeout timer.

```js
setTimeout(console.log, 500n, "I waited 500 ms");
```

However I got this error thrown:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number`

I tried to do this:

```js
setTimeout(console.log, Number(500n), "I waited 500 ms");
```

However I am not sure if the 500 will still be converted to a big integer.

Another thing I tried to do was to convert it using the `++` operator however it threw me the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number`

```js
let _500 = 500n
setTimeout(console.log, _500++, "I waited 500 ms");
```

Comment: And what is the setTimeout funcion?

Comment: If you convert it, you are just passing a regular Number, so there's no point. How exactly are you "exceeding the 32 bit integer limit"?

Comment: You cant. It  expects an integer. But to be fair I cant think of any case where you would put a delay even closely exceeding the limit.

Comment: I am trying to iterate over a array of element while incrementing a timeout ms variable

Comment: But you are aware how long a delay of 2147483647ms would be? None is gonna leave the client open for ~25 days.

Comment: No I wasn't realzing that my timeout gonna make the client open for 25 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You are going to get [inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468650/691711) at best setting timeout to max value. Use a [cron](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples) tool for this.

If this isn't for a server, I'm not sure that any user will keep their browser open for the 24 days (2147483647 millis) that would hit the limit of `setTimeout`. If this is for a server, a cron tab is really going to serve you better.

If you absolutely must use a large value, you could set up a wrapper that would create new timeouts as the previous one ends until you have waited the entire time.

Comment: What is a "cron tool"

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=g7hTYOSpFszbgwfq0JmoCA&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYFPGkxoXiEuX8-8DDevNlfkxKqNBBFfv&q=cron+tool&oq=cron+tool&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOg4IABDqAhC0AhDZAhDlAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgUILhCxAzoCCC46CwgAELEDEMcBEKMCOggIABDHARCvAToECAAQCjoICAAQFhAKEB5Q0A5Y0xlg6RtoAXAAeACAAW-IAcwGkgEDNi4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCA&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwik98nR17rvAhXM7eAKHWpoBoUQ4dUDCAg&uact=5

Answer (score 3):

> Browsers including Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox store the delay as a 32-bit signed integer internally. This causes an integer overflow when using delays larger than 2,147,483,647 ms (about 24.8 days), resulting in the timeout being executed immediately.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value

Comment: I guess this is the case for node js aswell. Am I rightÉ

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 would be just fine, know your bit limits

Comment: It's not because in my program I increase the 500 by 1000 each time a loop has finish and it reaches the 32 bit integer