# JavaScript setTimeout doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I read recently that `setTimeout()`'s timeout limit is `2147483647`.

When I set the timeout to `2147483648` the program changes it to `1` but doesn't do when the timeout is set to `52147483648`.

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log(2147483648), 2147483648) // will fire in 1ms
setTimeout(() => console.log(52147483648), 52147483648) // will fire in a long time
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Please may you add a [mcve] to the question demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does setTimeout() "break" for large millisecond delay values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468607/why-does-settimeout-break-for-large-millisecond-delay-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Documentation, the setTimeOut Function supports a maximum of 24.8 days [[MDN Ref]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value) that is equal to 2147483647

Thus when you do 2147483648 you essentially get is (2147483648 - 2147483647 = 1)

However, when you use 52147483648 as per the epoch time converter this is only 17 days ahead in the future which is less than 24.8 days thus it does not convert it

Comment: Thanks but I want to know this section, how is it: "However, when you use 52147483648 as per the epoch time converter this is only 17 days ahead in the future which is less than 24.8 days thus it does not convert it"

Comment: See if this help you undetstand the convertion https://www.epochconvert.com/programming/javascript#:~:text=Get%20Epoch%20or%20Unix%20Timestamp%20in%20JavaScript,getTime()%3B

Answer (score 0):

Maximum delay value
Browsers including Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox store the delay as a 32-bit signed integer internally. This causes an integer overflow when using delays larger than 2,147,483,647 ms (about 24.8 days), resulting in the timeout being executed immediately.

[settimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)