# >>> (Zero-fill right shift) Elaboration

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good does zero-fill bit-shifting by 0 do? (a >>> 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0)

I was looking at `array.indexOf()`, and I'm aware that IE7 does not natively support that. I was reading the MDC and saw [their example of how to prototype it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) into browsers that don't support it. I'm reading through it trying to understand how everything works, but I'm not sure I'm understanding it 100%. The main cause for confusion is the bitwise operators, specifically `>>>`. I'm not sure what this operator is useful for. Below is the way that they're using it. Can anyone explain exactly what it's useful for and why you can't just `if (t.length === 0)`?

```
 var t = Object(this);  
 var len = t.length >>> 0;  
 if (len === 0)  
   return -1;
```

Comment: I read that too just now, and I'm still not 100%. His explanation seems to say it ensures it is a non negative number... but like one of the comments, I wasn't aware array.length could return a negative number.

Comment: read my comment to @Marcel in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/#3082073), the methods of `Array.prototype` are **intentionally generic** that means that they can be used on Array-like objects. Moreover, the Mozilla implementation of those Array methods, tries to mimic the behavior of the [ECMA-262 Specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.14) as best as possible, and the `>>>` operator is the shortest way to mimic the [`ToUint32` internal operation](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.6), used internally by all those methods...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It allows `indexOf` to be called on array-like objects that might have weird `length` properties.

For example:

```
var fakeArray = { length: -3, '0': true, '1': false, '2': null };
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what's an example of an 'array-like' object?

Comment: @Stanley: Any object with a `length` proeprty and properties named `0`, `1`, `2`, ...

Comment: Oh, your edit really cleared things up... I didn't even think of it like that. Thanks.

Comment: @Stanley: What you get out of doing `document.getElementsByTagName('span')`. That's a NodeList, which acts like an array but isn't. There are others in javascriptland but that's the most common. Though, I'm not aware of any array-like object where length can be negative.

Comment: @slebetman, Note that with [host objects](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_4.3.8) -such NodeLists- [the specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.14) doesn't guarantees that Array methods such `indexOf`, `slice`, etc, can be applied to them: "Whether the indexOf function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent."

Comment: @CMS: I was answering to `what's an example of an 'array-like' object?`.