# Why are the MDC prototype functions written this way?

Tags: javascript

In MDC there are plenty of code snippets that meant to implement support for new ECMAScript standards in browsers that don't support them, such as the `Array.prototype.map` function:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

What's the benefit (if there's any) of using this function rather than

```
function(fun, thisp)
{
  // same code, just without the "var thisp = arguments[1];" line:
  "use strict";

  if (this === void 0 || this === null)
    throw new TypeError();

  var t = Object(this);
  var len = t.length >>> 0;
  if (typeof fun !== "function")
    throw new TypeError();

  var res = new Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (i in t)
      res[i] = fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
  }

  return res;
}
```

, `var t = Object(this);` rather than `var t = this;` and `var len = t.length >>> 0;` rather than `var len = t.length;`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

This was covered pretty well in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0) Basically it makes sure the number is a non-negative 32 bit int.

As for the Object constructor:

```
var t = Object(this);
```

If *this* is null or undefined, it'll return an empty object.  From the [MDC Docs on Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

> The Object constructor creates an
>   object wrapper for the given value. If
>   the value is null or undefined, it
>   will create and return an empty
>   object, otherwise, it will return an
>   object of type that corresponds to the
>   given value.

They're both just quick ways to do error correction.

EDIT:  I was thinking way too hard about the thisp part.  I was assuming that using the arguments array was a way to ensure arguments were defaulting to undefined, but they do that on their own anyway. Mike Hofer got it right in the comments.  It's Mozilla's coding style to indicate optional parameters.  Function.call defaults to global if null or undefined is passed in as the first argument. From the [MDC Docs on Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> thisArg:
>   Determines the value of **this** inside
>   fun. If thisArg is null or undefined,
>   **this** will be the global object.
>   Otherwise, **this** will be equal to
>   Object(thisArg) (which is thisArg if
>   thisArg is already an object, or a
>   String, Boolean, or Number if thisArg
>   is a primitive value of the
>   corresponding type). Therefore, it is
>   always true that typeof **this** ==
>   "object" when the function executes.

Comment: Thanks! (but do you know about that `function(fun, thisp)` staff?)

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I missed that, edit coming momentarily.

Comment: `function(fun /*, thisp */)` is a coding *style* that indicates that thisp is an optional parameter. `fun`, of course, is a delegate function later invoked using `fun.call`, passing `thisp` as the "context" (that is, it will become the value of `this` when the function executes).

Comment: @Mike-Hofner Thanks, I was thinking way too hard about that :/

Answer (score 3):

`var t = Object(this);`

Is based on the ES5 specification. It specifically state that `this` should be passed into the `Object` constructor.

If you look closely at the exact algorithm specified in the ES5 spec then the method provided by Mozilla mirrors it almost exactly (it's limited by ES3 features). This is the reason this code seems to have a few quirks.

Here is the ES5 specification:

> When the map method is called with one
>   or two arguments, the following steps
>   are taken:

1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
2. Let lenValue  be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length".
3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
4. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) where Array is the standard builtin constructor with that name and len is the value of len.
7. Let k be 0.
8. Repeat, while k < len

   1. Let Pk be ToString(k).
   2. Let kPresent be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
   3. If kPresent is true, then

      - Let kValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument Pk.
      - Let mappedValue be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of callbackfn with T as 
        the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
      - Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of A with arguments Pk, Property 
        Descriptor {[[Value]]: mappedValue, [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, 
        [[Configurable]]: true}, and false.
      - Increase k by 1.
9. Return A.

> Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.

Notice that step one specifically says you should call `Object(this)`

> Let lenValue be the result of calling
>   the [[Get]] internal method of O with
>   the argument "length".
>
> Let len be
>   ToUint32(lenValue).

Step 2 and 3 specifically say get `t.length` then call `ToUint32` which is implemented as `>>> 0` here.

The actual signature mentioned in the specification is

> Array.prototype.map ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )

In the above signature `callbackfn` is a required argument and `[ ]` is an array of optional arguments which only contains one `thisArg`.

Mozilla have mirrored this in their definition of `function(fun /*, thisp */) {`  to specify that `thisp` is an optional argument and it's clear this is the case from the function signature rather then from looking at the code.