# Right shift operator - Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand why i.e. `Math.random()*255>>0;` will skip/remove all the decimals. Same thing happens if I write `>>1` or `>>2` instead of 0.

I came over another SO-post that said `x >> n` operator could be looked at as  `x / 2^n`. That still doesn't explain why the decimals goes away.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Phil How is this a duplicate of the link you're referring to? >> and >>> are not the same thing?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, reading comprehension fail

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a shift by 0 truncate the decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125421/why-does-a-shift-by-0-truncate-the-decimal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to spec, certain numerical operations are required to convert arguments to 32 bit integers first. (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.2)

> The production `ShiftExpression` : `ShiftExpression` >> `AdditiveExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `ShiftExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be GetValue(`lref`).
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `AdditiveExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be GetValue(`rref`).
> 5. Let `lnum` be ToInt32(`lval`). *← The number is converted to a 32 bit integer here*
> 6. Let `rnum` be ToUint32(`rval`).
> 7. Let `shiftCount` be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of `rnum`, that is, compute `rnum & 0x1F`.
> 8. Return the result of performing a sign-extending right shift of `lnum` by `shiftCount` bits. The most significant bit is propagated. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.