# Twos complement same code python / JavaScript different results

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

In python 2.7, the following code returns the *correct* result (**-18027917**)

```
from __future__ import print_function

def twos_comp(val, bits):
    if (val & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0:
        val -= 1 << bits
     return val

valBinary = "110111011001110101001110011"
print(twos_comp(int(valBinary, 2), len(valBinary)))
```

---

In JavaScript (Node.js) the following code returns an *incorrect* result (**1995238003**)

```
function toTwosComplement(val, bits) {
    if ((val & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0) {
        val -= (val - 1) << bits;
    }
    return val;
}

valBinary = "110111011001110101001110011";  // same as python example
console.log(toTwosComplement(parseInt(valBinary, 2), valBinary.length));
```

Evidently there is something different about the behaviour of the bit operators (or int / parseInt) but I haven't been able to see what it is.

Comment: Do the results change if you pass the right values for `val` and `bits` directly? That would rule out `parseInt` as cause, leaving `toTwosComplement`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First,

```
val -= (val - 1) << bits;
```

and

```
val -= 1 << bits
```

are not equivalent.

Since your binary string is 27 digits long, this is most likely the source of your problem.

---

More generally, the two languages have very different definitions of the term number.

Python has [arbitrary precision integers](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

> Long integers have unlimited precision.

By contrast, JavaScript has [IEEE 64b doubles pretending to be integers](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html) and bitwise operators that [truncate their operands to 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125421/why-does-a-shift-by-0-truncate-the-decimal).

> Number is 64-bit floating point, similar to Java's double and Double. There is no integer type. Division between two integers may produce a fractional result.

This means you can store at most [52 bits of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats), and if the highest order bit is greater than 2**52, then low order bits are truncated.

---

Because of the floating point nature of JavaScript, the least significant bits of a large binary number might be rounded off, and the most significant bits might be thrown out by (`<<`).

Comment: Thanks Mike (and Carl).  I must have messed up the guilty line at some point but, having fixed it, the javascript version now seems to work.  I accepted Mike's answer because it provides significant additional info but upticked Carls because it too was correct.  Both of you guys are Champions!

Answer (score 1):

Why do these lines not match?

Python:

```
    val -= 1 << bits
```

JS:

```
    val -= (val - 1) << bits;
```