# How to truncate large integers during bitwise operations to mimic JavaScript in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, bit-manipulation

I've found that working with integers in Ruby causes them to act different than JS when their binary representation is larger than 32 bits.

```
a = 144419633058839139324
b = 3903086624
```

JS:

```
a >> 0; => 1482555392
b >> 0; => -391880672
```

Ruby:

```
a >> 0 => 144419633058839139324
[a].pack('V').unpack('V').first => 1482560508
[b].pack('V').unpack('V').first => 3903086624
```

My question is how can I convert my Ruby code to give the same return values JS?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to do this, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125421/why-does-a-shift-by-0-truncate-the-decimal

Comment: what do you mean by truncate ? why would you do that to 
Integer ?

Comment: Truncate meaning removing part of the binary representation of the integer and returning the truncated portion. Essentially in Ruby:

    bin = `a.to_s(2) => "1111101010000111001100110110001100101011000010111100001001111111100"`

    `bin.to_i(2) => a`
    `bin[-32..-1].to_i(2) => 1482560508`

Ruby correctly truncates the value, however the issue is with JS rounding the value. A program I'm implementing in Ruby from JS relies on returning the same JS values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great question. I did some experimentation trying to figure out exactly what operations JavaScript is doing, but then I thought, "I bet the spec says." Sure enough, it did!

First I checked out the [Bitwise Shift Operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7) section, and what I learned from that is what you already knew: Before doing bitwise operations, JavaScript converts its operands to 32-bit integers. For that, it links to the definition of an "abstract operation" (i.e. an algorithm to be implemented by JavaScript engines) called [ToInt32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5). Happily, it's really easy to follow:

> #### ToInt32: (Signed 32 Bit Integer)
>
> The abstract operation ToInt32 converts its argument to one of 2<sup>32</sup> integer values in the range -2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive. This abstract operation functions as follows:
>
> 1. Let *number* be the result of calling [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on the input argument. *[This just converts non-numeric values like booleans and strings into numbers.]*
> 2. If *number* is **NaN**, **+0**, **−0**, **+∞**, or **−∞**, return **+0**.
> 3. Let *posInt* be `sign(`*number*`) * floor(abs(`*number*`))`. *[[`sign`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2) returns -1 if* number *is negative or 1 if it's positive.]*
> 4. Let *int32bit* be *posInt* modulo 2<sup>32</sup>; that is, a finite integer value k of Number type with positive sign and less than 2<sup>32</sup> in magnitude such that the mathematical difference of *posInt* and k is mathematically an integer multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>.
> 5. If *int32bit* is greater than or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>, return *int32bit* − 2<sup>32</sup>, otherwise return *int32bit*.

We can translate this directly into Ruby (I've numbered the steps 1–5 as comments):

```
def to_int32(number)
  # (1)(2)
  begin
    sign = number < 0 ? -1 : 1
    abs = number.abs
    return 0 if abs == 0 || abs == Float::INFINITY
  rescue
    return 0
  end

  pos_int = sign * abs.floor  # (3)
  int_32bit = pos_int % 2**32 # (4)

  # (5)
  return int_32bit - 2**32 if int_32bit >= 2**31
  int_32bit
end
```

So, does it work?

```
a = 144419633058839130000
puts to_int32(a)
# => 1482551184

b = 3903086624
puts to_int32(b)
# => -391880672
```

Seems legit!

Now, I'm sure there are more concise and probably faster ways to do this, but this should get you started.