# What does this one do: w = 200 + 200 * Math.random() << 0;

Tags: bitwise-operators, freewalljs

```
    var temp = "<div class='cell' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(i/photo/{index}.jpg)'></div>";
    var w = 1, html = '', limitItem = 49;
    for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
        w = 200 +  200 * Math.random() << 0;
        html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, 200).replace(/\{width\}/g, w).replace("{index}", i + 1);
    }
    $("#freewall").html(html);
```

I'm not really good in Javascript bitwise operation especially the left shift operator (the <<). Can anyone explain to me why the developer uses that with Math.random() times 200 and plus 200 for the width? The code is excerpt from freewall.js example codes.

Answer (score 0):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

So, the author wants it to be somewhere between 200 and 400px wide. PX need to be integers, so the author then uses the left shift of a 0 to truncate right of the decimal. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12125432/5314386 for more about the truncation.