# What << does in Math.random() * Math.pow(36, 2) << 0

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

Wondering what the `<<` does in this:

```
Math.random() * Math.pow(36, 2) << 0
```

Not sure how to use that in practice.

Comment: you could also wrap everything in `Math.floor()` or use `| 0` at the end. its basically just flooring.

Comment: to be honest i'd have written it like that: `Math.random() * 36 ** 2 | 0` Math.pow is obsolete in my humble opinion

Comment: good to know :))

Comment: keep in mind '| 0' will not protect you against integer overflows. it really casts a double to an int. you could get a negative number by doing this: `3498723498723 | 0`

Answer (score 1):

It truncates the number / converts it to an integer. You can test this for yourself:

```
console.log(12.345 << 0); // 12
```

— This question is very similar to [Why does a shift by 0 truncate the decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125421/why-does-a-shift-by-0-truncate-the-decimal)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

```
a = Math.pow(36, 2)
1296
a = Math.random() * a
477.5906135469167
a = a << 0
477
```