# What does unsigned right shift zero positions mean?

Tags: javascript, c++

I need to port a Javascript function to C++. And during the porting process I found this line of code:

```
return (randseed[3]>>>0) / ((1 << 31)>>>0);
```

My question is: what does unsigned right shift zero bytes to the right means  ??? What is the point of shifting zero bytes??? And what would be the equivalent to C/C++ of it?

This is the function I am porting:

```
    function rand() {
            // based on Java's String.hashCode(), expanded to 4 32bit values
            var t = randseed[0] ^ (randseed[0] << 11);

            randseed[0] = randseed[1];
            randseed[1] = randseed[2];
            randseed[2] = randseed[3];
            randseed[3] = (randseed[3] ^ (randseed[3] >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8));

            return (randseed[3]>>>0) / ((1 << 31)>>>0);
    }
```

(Source: https://github.com/ethereum/blockies/blob/master/blockies.js)

And this is my current port:

```
double_t Accounts::rand(int *rand_seed) {
    int v1,v2;
    v1=rand_seed[0];
    v2=rand_seed[0] << 11;
    int t=v1 ^ v2;

    rand_seed[0]=rand_seed[1];
    rand_seed[1]=rand_seed[2];
    rand_seed[2]=rand_seed[3];
    v1=rand_seed[3] >> 19;
    v2=t>>8;
    rand_seed[3]=rand_seed[3] ^ v1 ^ t ^ v2;

    uint v=rand_seed[3];
    uint d=1<<31;

    double_t output=v / d;
    return output;
}
```

Maybe someone with C++ knowledge might check if I did it correcly?

I also added printouts of the variables inside the function, expecting right shift zero bytes produce different results

```
      var before,after
      before=randseed[3]     
      after=(randseed[3]>>>0)
      console.log('before='+before+', after='+after)
      return (randseed[3]>>>0) / ((1 << 31)>>>0);
```

But the console.log showed no difference:

```
before=1458668765, after=1458668765
before=1818856068, after=1818856068
before=622943643, after=622943643
```

Comment: Forcing js to treat them as unsigned 32-bit ints, maybe? [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1822769)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, i think you got it right.

Comment: It truncates the value. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125421/why-does-a-shift-by-0-truncate-the-decimal) similar post