# what does the symbol >> means in javascript

Tags: javascript

What does the `>>` symbol mean? On [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), there's a line that looks like this:

```
var i = 0, l = this.length >> 0, curr;
```

Comment: what is bitwise shifting and why is it used here?so how does bitwise shifting relates to the code on the page??

thanks btw.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=bitwise+shift

Comment: You should check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's bitwise shifting.

Let's take the number 7, which in binary is `0b00000111`

`7 << 1` shifts it one bit to the left, giving you `0b00001110`, which is 14

Similarly, you can shift to the right: `7 >> 1` will cut off the last bit, giving you `0b00000011` which is 3.

**[Edit]**
In JavaScript, numbers are stored as *floats*. However, when shifting you need integer values, so using bit shifting on JavaScript values will convert it from float to integer.

**In JavaScript, shifting by 0 bits will round the number down* (integer rounding)** *(Better phrased: it will convert the value to integer)*

```
> a = 7.5;
7.5
> a >> 0
7
```

*: Unless the number is negative.

Sidenote: since JavaScript's integers are 32-bit, avoid using bitwise shifts unless you're absolutely sure that you're not going to use large numbers.

**[Edit 2]**
`this.length >> 0` will also make a *copy* of the number, instead of taking a reference to it. Although I have no idea why anyone would want that.

Comment: @JanDvorak Added that to my answer

Comment: Also, if the nubmer is stored as a string, it will be converted to number.

Comment: Alternatives: `a||0`, `~~a`

Comment: In that code they are shifting array.length to zero. I doubt that array.length ever will be fractional. So what is the point to do this there?

Comment: @SergeyS if `array` is not a real array then `length` could be anything. The method could could be grafted to anything.

Comment: @JanDvorak But that code is added to the prototype of the Array object, so it will always be an array, right?

Comment: @SergeyS No idea. In the example you provided it seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: How it can be not a real array, if we are adding this function to its prototype. The only way I see is if someone replaced 'length' property for array. In that case all the code will be useless anyway, and bitwise shift does not help really)

Comment: @SergeyS `Array.prototype.reduce.call({length:"3.14"})`

Comment: @SergeyS or even `{length:"3.14", reduce:Array.prototype.reduce}.reduce()`

Comment: Looks like a nonsense, what output would be. I guess function will crash anyway

Comment: @SergeyS `Array.prototype.reduce.call({length:"3.14"}, function(a,b){return a+b})` should return `"undefinedundefinedundefined"` (since `{length:"3.14}[0..2]` are all `undefined`).

Comment: Cool, if I ever will want 'undefinedundefinedundefined' I will be using your approach. But wait, what if I provide length equal to letter (not a fractional number), bitwise shift will help me?))

Comment: @SergeyS a non-number applied in an integer context (bitwise operators) will be cast to `0`, so `length` will be zero.

Comment: @SergeyS Calling array functions on pseudo-arrays is pretty common. Admittably, the pseudo-arrays won't usually be degenerate like mine is. It's still a good idea to cast the length to integer.

Comment: Jan Dvorak, could you please provide answer here (not in comments) with some practical usages of this function, where length is not a whole integer. Really appreciated.

Comment: @SergeyS I'm not saying that casting the length to integer is actually useful. I'm just saying that length _can_ be non-integer and casting to integer might seem like a good idea to the authors of ECMAscript.

Comment: @SergeyS personally, I can't think of any practical case where this is useful - you can always cast to integer yourself in your pseudo-arrays. However, it is easy for the authors of the  `Array.prototype.reduce` as well, so they do so that you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in many other languages `>>` operator (among `<<` and `>>>`) is a [bitwise shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts).