# Javascript: Why use >>> 0

Tags: javascript

Why would you write `x = x >>> 0`?

According to mozilla `a >>> b`:

> Shifts a in binary representation b bits to the right, discarding bits
>   shifted off, and shifting in zeros from the left.

and shifting by 0 bits doesn't seem that useful.

Comment: [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0)

Comment: [Here is your complete answer . Check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0