# What is the purpose of >>> bitwise shift operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I've seen in some code samples it being used in scenarios like this:

```
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

What's confusing is that it didn't even need to be there, I'm not sure why this addition was added. MDN uses it a lot in there JavaScript prototype backwards compatibility additions as well.

```
var len = t.length; // has the same result
```

**What purpose does the `>>>` serve (especially in this scenario) ?**

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> Zero-fill right shift a >>> b Shifts a in binary representation b (<
>   32) bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off, and shifting in
>   zeros from the left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What good does zero-fill bit-shifting by 0 do? (a >>> 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0)

Comment: len = t.length || 0; works as well and is more readable, even if zero gets assessed twice.

Comment: @dandavis: You mean `len = t.length | 0` I guess

Comment: @Bergi: no, what's that?

Comment: @dandavis: The proper [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) that is required to cast the value to a 32bit int.

Comment: @Bergi: int? what's that? i thought this was a js question... my code was saying "if no length, then default to zero". if you use only one pipe ("|"), then you will turn 45.34 into 45...

Comment: Yes it's a javascript question. Yeah I typically would just do `t.length || 0` but I guess the ` >>> ` can be used in a similar fashion in this instance.

Comment: @dandavis: Please read the page I linked. Yes, it's javascript, and yes, it's an [int](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5). And it is indeed supposed to truncate, or have you ever seen a list of length 45.34?

Comment: @Bergi: who said anything about a list? since we're given no context, .length could easily be a measurement of time or a textual description like "small", "medium", or "large".

Comment: @dandavis: "*MDN uses it a lot in there JavaScript prototype backwards compatibility additions as well.*" should be enough context - those compat snippets are for the `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be used to typecast the length value to zero.

```
x = {};  //create object
x.length //is undefined
x.length >>> 0 //returns 0
```